# How to wait until a task has finished and then continue, within the event dispatch thread?

Tags: java, events, swing, swingworker

I have a program, a game, with GUI made with Swing.

The GUI is comprised of my own class which inherits JFrame and holds a JPanel with CardLayout, which has multiple JPanels as cards.

On one of these panels there is a Button which starts the game and the game view is located on one of the cards (the view object, which has its own class which inherits JPanel, is added to the card in the constructor of the JFrame).

Now the prologue:

I press the JButton, so I jump to the Event Dispatch Thread to execute the actionPerformed method.

In this method I first flip to the card that holds the view panel, then instantiate the level i'm going to play and the game engine (which is instantiated according to the level). Then i call repaint on the view object (which should end up with the game being painted in the apllication window) and THEN I call my game engine object to start the game loop.

My problem is:

When i press the button, the game engine begins to run properly (i see it from the prints in console), but my GUI freezes and won't refresh to show the game view. When i remove the snippet of code that starts the game loop, the game view shows on the screen normally, nothing moves though, because the game loop hasn't been started.

So I have deducted that, because in Java everything doesn't happen in the order it is written, the game loop begins to run BEFORE the other operations in the actionperformed method have been completed.

Here is the relevant snippet from the actionperformed method
kortti = card
kentta = level
valikkopaneeli = the panel that has cardlayout
aloitusnappula = the button that starts the game
Peli = the class i made that inherits JFrame

```
if (e.getSource() == aloitusnappula) {
```

CardLayout kortti = (CardLayout)valikkopaneeli.getLayout();
  Kentta kentta = new Kentta("testikentta.txt");
  kortti.show(valikkopaneeli, "Peli");
  Peli.this.pack();
  Peli.this.setVisible(true);
  aloita(kentta);
    }

and here is a snippet of the aloita(kentta) method:

```
public void aloita(Kentta kentta) {
 moottori = new Pelimoottori(Peli.this, kentta);
 nakyma.repaint();
 moottori.peliLooppi();
}
```

where Pelimoottori = the Game Engine class
nakyma = the view object
peliLooppi() = the method in the Game Engine class that starts the Game Loop

If I'd remove moottori.peliLooppi() call from the aloita method, the game view would show normally.

I tried to google some answers and the farthest I've got is somehow doing it with SwingWorker, but somehow it doesn't sound like a good way of doing what i want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you start your engine loop inside the edt. If so, it's BAD.

From the edt call another thread, and manage your engine from this new thread. For gui update, recall edt with [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Or best, use a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

To read some good english language documentation about long term job in swing, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Don't use Thread.sleep.

Comment: If I make my game engine runnable and make the run() method to just excecute the game loop method, will the Thread.sleep call from the game loop method only halt the thread my game engine is running in? Sorry if I'm confusing.

Comment: I've upadated my contribution to propose you a tutorial.

Comment: So I should use SwingWorker to run the game Loop?

Comment: Yes, or use Swing Timer, as says camickr. It's your choice. The only sure thing is **don't use sleep**. And read the tutorials, and make some tests, and...

Comment: I process my keypresses within the game engine object with a method that gets called by the KeyListener registered to my GUI. I got the game view to show correctly with both the SwingWorker and Swing Timer, but both have the same problem, the game engine doesn't respond to keys at all. As a matter of fact, the KeyListener doesn't respond to me pressing keys at all...

Comment: Have you a very little test which show the problem ? About your KeyListener, is your game engine which doesn't respond, or is your listener which listen nothing ?

Comment: i've tried registering the listener to all possible places, but when i press any key, i see from a print i have put in place int the keyPressed method that the listener doesn't even recognize a key being pressed

Comment: It was a focus issue, solved with a little help from Component.requestFocusInWindow()

Answer (score 1):

> When i remove the snippet of code that starts the game loop, the game view shows on the screen normally

Sounds like you are probably using a while loop with a Thread.sleep.

A better approach is to use a [Swing Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the "looping" of your game.